# HTML in Link Label

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to have the label be HMTL (font awesome icon) but it's only displaying it as text.  See sample below:

```
columns:[       
    {
        title:"Order", width:100, field:"url_name", align:"center", headerSort:false, formatter:"link", formatterParams:{
            urlField:"url",
            label: "<i class="fas fa-link"></i>",
            target:"_blank",
        }       
    }   
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom formatter:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/format#format-custom

```
columns:[       
    {
        title:"Order", width:100, field:"url_name", align:"center", headerSort:false
, formatter: (c, p) => {
    return `<a href='${p.urlField}' target='_blank'><i class='fas fa-link'></i></a>`
}, formatterParams:{
            urlField:"url",
        }       
    }   
]
```

Comment: The source code for Tabulator has the `label` field being sanitized, so it won't accept HTML.  This is the correct answer.